How to replace "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server" with the new "@angular/ssr"
I am trying to update an existing Angular Ionic project with the new "@angular/ssr", because SSR just isn't working the way I want.
ng add @angular/ssr is kind of difficult, because it messes up my existing configuration. I believe it assumes an Angular Standalone setup. And it produces a ton of errors while building.
I guess the first question would be, is it even possible to get SSR working without the new standalone mode?
Second and main question:
Is it possible, and how, to replace the "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server"?
   "serve-ssr": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build",
        "serverTarget": "app:server"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:production",
          "serverTarget": "app:server:production"
        },
        "qa": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:qa",
          "serverTarget": "app:server:qa"
        }
      }
    },


I am hoping to get it working again. No need for standalone components, prerendering routes, no need for lazy loaded components. Just Angular, Ionic and SSR.

Please post the code as text, not screenshot.
